# Dynamically adding UI Bootstrap Popover on an icon?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I dynamically add icons in my Angular app that indicate a different source based on color.

This is in this function:

```
function getDataSource(datasource) {

        switch (datasource) {

            case 'A1':
                return '<span><i class=\"fa fa-circle blue\"></i></span>';
            case 'A2':
                return '<span><i class=\"fa fa-circle green\"></i></span>';
            case 'A3':
                return '<span><i class=\"fa fa-circle yellow\"></i></span>';
            case 'A4':
                return '<span><i class=\"fa fa-circle red\"></i></span>';
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is have a popover in those spans or in the icons themselves that display a group of related links. I have the ui.bootstrap module as a dependency for the particular module these data source icons are in.

When I tried using popover before nothing showed.

How do I add popover elements to my app, dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

function getDataSource(datasource) {

```
    switch (datasource) {

        case 'A1':
            return '<span data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover"><i class=\"fa fa-circle blue\"></i></span>';
        case 'A2':
            return '<span data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover"><i class=\"fa fa-circle green\"></i></span>';
        case 'A3':
            return '<span data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover"><i class=\"fa fa-circle yellow\"></i></span>';
        case 'A4':
            return '<span data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover"><i class=\"fa fa-circle red\"></i></span>';
    }
}
```

And then activate them with JS

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
    });
</script>
```

This will activate all data-toggle="popovers" on the page.

Comment: It looks like when it compiles and I check the element it only compiles the title attribute and none of the ui bootstrap attributes.